# C#UserControl DPI scaling issue

Tags: c#, dpi

I'm having an issue with DPI scaling in C#. As I am using a 4K Monitor with scaling at 150%, I've set my Form's AutoScalingMode property to "dpi". Here everything is fine. Then I create a User Control, I also set AutoScalingMode to "dpi", load it into a panel inside my form with this code

```
        UC_Weather ucWeather = new UC_Weather();
        PANEL_Main.Controls.Clear();

        ucWeather.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        PANEL_Main.Controls.Add(ucWeather);
```

and the right edge of the User Control is clipped.
I've also tried all the other properties for the AutoScalingMode property in my User Control and clearly "dpi" is the best, but there is still this clipped right edge.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the `UserControl`'s `AutoScalingMode` to `Inherit`. It seems having both `Form` and `UserControl` to `Dpi` can cause issues - see [this report](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967578/child-controls-on-a-usercontrol-may-get-clipped-in-a-system-with-a-low).

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work, I already saw this and tried. It makes things even worse...